# Dispatch Thread Groups Error

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am running computer vision algorithms on a video feed I'm getting in real time. I'm running these operations/algorithms using `DispatchQueue` asynchronously. However, I am getting the following error, which I cannot interpret:

`[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup:]:949: failed assertion (threadgroupsPerGrid.width(0) * threadgroupsPerGrid.y(12) * threadgroupsPerGrid.depth(1))(0) must not be 0.'`

What is this error?

Answer (score 0):

This message is stating that there was an assertion failure caused by an assertion in [`[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldispatchthreadgroupsindirectarguments).

As far as I understand it, it was asserted that this expression:

```
threadgroupsPerGrid.width * threadgroupsPerGrid.y * threadgroupsPerGrid.depth
```

should not be `0`, but it was `0`, causing this assertion failure. Additionally, they've annotated the values of these variables:

- `threadgroupsPerGrid.width` was `0`
- `threadgroupsPerGrid.y` was `12`
- `threadgroupsPerGrid.depth` was `1`
- `threadgroupsPerGrid.width * threadgroupsPerGrid.y * threadgroupsPerGrid.depth` evaluated to `0`

This invalid state is likely a result of you passing invalid arguments to [`[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldispatchthreadgroupsindirectarguments). If I had to guess, the issue is probably that `threadgroupsPerGrid.width` was `0`.